# Ubuntu 15.10 presents the same problems with booting as older versions

Tags: boot, 15.10, toshiba-satellite

I am struggling for days to boot my freshly installed Ubuntu on my Toshiba Satelite machine (AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 4). This laptop was bought recently, in December 2015. It had Windows 10 preinstalled and obviously it had no problems with booting, but after eliminating that nightmare operating system and installing Ubuntu 14 I could not boot my computer other than from my live USB flashdrive. A lot of people suggested me to install Ubuntu 15.10 instead, so I did, and still the same issue.

Please note that I did switched off the secure boot, I also did prioritize hard drive for booting.

Comment: How have you installed Ubuntu? Your problem is either in installing or in booting. It has nothing to do with version of Ubuntu

Comment: I have created a bootalble USB-flashdrive and installed it creating 4 partitions: swap, root, home and BIOS boot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your computer has EFI support and when installing Ubuntu onto the hard-drive and setting up manual partitions you are skipping the creation of an EFI partition so that Ubuntu will boot properly...  Do an automatic 64-bit install and let Ubuntu set partitions to see if that works.